# Error en Ajax de JQuery y controlador Spring mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Estoy enviando un POST desde ajax a un controlador con Spring mvc, todo funcionaba correctamente, el controlador recibía los datos y trabajaba con ellos, el problema ha aparecido cuando he querido ejecutar una función en el success de ajax, he comprobado que no entra y devuelve error: Not Found, no se que puede pasar porque no retorna a success si todo funciona correctamente, dejo el código:

Javascript

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/HelloSpringMVC/j',
  data: {t: JSON.stringify(objeto), l: JSON.stringify(objeto2)},//put search js object directly here
  success :function(result) {
   // do what ever you want with data

      $("#res2").text("Success");
    pedirDatos();
 }, error: function (xhr, status, error) {
           $("#res2").text(error);
        }
});
```

Controlador

```
    @RequestMapping(value ="/j", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public String posted(String t, String l) {
        System.out.println("Tarjetas" +t);
        return "sucess";
}
```

Comment: El controller es un @Controller o un @RestController?

Comment: Si usas un JSP o similar, es posible que tengas una errata en tu método: debería ser `return "success";`, con dos **c**

Comment: Gracias, pero ese no es el error, no utilizo JSP, el ajax lo tengo en un .js   de una web html, inicialmente no retornaba nada en el método posted, pero pensé que necesitaba retornar algo para que lo recogiera el success del .js

Comment: Con "Not Found" quieres decir un 404?

Comment: me refiero a que $("#res2").text(error); imprime Not Found, en vez de ir a la funcion success se invoca la funcion error y muestra eso en pantalla

Comment: pues tiene pinta de que no se está llamando realmente al método del controlador... ¿te aparece algo en la consola del servidor? ¿Tiene el controlador una anotación @RequestMapping también?

Comment: Si en el código aparece, creo que si se está llamando ya que en la consola del servidor si muestra los datos que envío, tengo un System.out.println("Datos"+ t) y me muestra bien los datos

Answer (score 1):

Mi problema es que faltaba @ResponseBody

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/j", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String posted(String t, String l) {
    System.out.println("Tarjetas" +t);
    return "success";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu controlador debe ir de esta manera:

```
   @RequestMapping(value ="/j", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   @ResponseBody
     public String posted(String t, String l) {
        System.out.println("Tarjetas" +t);
        return "sucess";
    }
```

Falta agregar el @ResponseBody para que funcione según la documentación de Spring.

Fuente: [Consumable Media Types](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc)